Instance method 'application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)' nearly matches optional of protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate
import SwiftUI
import shared
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

      FirebaseApp.configure() //important
      
      //By default showPushNotification value is true.
      //When set showPushNotification to false foreground push  notification will not be shown.
      //You can still get notification content using #onPushNotification listener method.
      NotifierManager.shared.initialize(configuration: NotificationPlatformConfigurationIos(showPushNotification: true))
      
    return true
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
  }
    
}

@main
struct iOSApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

I'm using kmpNotifier.
I get the message Instance method 'application(:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'application(:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)' of protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate for func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
} specifically for deviceToken: Data
How can I fix the code to remove the warning?
